# What is the piece of wood that is often long and square in cross-section and used to make table legs or chair legs called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the above picture, you'll see 2 pieces of wood that are long and square in cross-section. They are used to make chair legs.

**What are they called?**

I don't think they are called "plank" but a plank is normally flat not square in cross-section like that.

Comment: I don't think English has any "dedicated" term for such ***pieces, sticks, lengths,...** of wood*. But if you were gonna make your own table, you probably wouldn't buy 4 metre-long lengths for the legs - you'd normally be buying a longer length and cutting them up yourself. Or maybe get someone at the lumber yard to cut up the 4-metre length you just bought, so the pieces will fit in your car.

Comment: whilst I'm sure there are technical terms used in DIY or carpentry (as shown in the answers), I wouldn't expect any such term to be widely understood, and certainly not commonly used, by most people (who don't do much wordworking). Like @FumbleFingers says you'd be more likely to here pretty generic terms like "stick", "piece", "bit", "length", etc

Comment: wood pieces for chair legs.  **Not plank** which has the wrong semantic trait. We already told you all about planks so why repeat it? Didn't you read all about planks and boards in your other question?

Comment: @Tristan: There certainly won't be any "technical terms used in DIY or carpentry" with any currency in *British* English. I worked on a wide range of building sites as summer jobs, then full-time for almost 2 years after college. Plus my father (a site foreman) and myself were pretty dedicated DIY-ers. If there was a word with any significant currency, I think I'd have heard it.

Answer (score 1):

You might call them **blanks**. *Merriam-Webster* defines this sense of *blank* as meaning “a piece of material prepared to be made into something (such as a key) by a further operation.”

Comment: That is not a woodworking term unless you maybe you call blocks of wood for carving "blanks".

Comment: Note, @Lambie, I didn’t assert that it **was** a woodworking term, but that one could use it (and be understood).  The OP doesn’t indicate that what is required is a term of art, so I offered what might be appropriate instead in a more colloquial setting. This is, after all, ELL, not a site about woodworking.

Comment: A search for "chair leg blanks" gets plenty of hits, including "chair leg turning blanks" (pieces as pictured above, to be turned in a lathe into round chair legs).  https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=chair+leg+blanks&ia=web   So, "blanks" isn't wrong and doesn't deserve downvotes.

Comment: From the first hit on the link in the last comment: "Turning blanks are wooden square posts that are intended to be turned and created into a new design."

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't downvote anything. Twasn't me.

Answer (score 0):

That is some square timber, or perhaps rectangular, about 20x30.

When talking about types of timber, the dimensions are referred to, traditionally in inches, hence stud-work might be build with "two-by-four", but more commonly nowadays in millimeters.

Other words, while talking about wood: A dowel has a circular cross section.  Slats are thin planks, used to cover something. Veneer is paper-thin that is stuck onto the surface of, for example, a tabletop. Lumber and timber have similar meanings. In British English timber tends to be more processed; lumber could be logs or roughly sawn wood; timber might be dried, cut, and planed smooth. In the US, exactly the opposite!